# 'onhashchange' not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, hashchange

I'm trying to detect hashchanged which works fine in every browser except chrome. For example, with this code:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}
```

The statement is never executed in Chrome but works in Firefox. I've seen a jQuery hashchange plugin on GitHub but didn't have any luck with that either.

Any ideas?

Comment: [**Works for me**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsr2bxru/1/) (Chrome 46.0.2490.80 on Linux; what version are you using?). My guess is that there's some unrelated error earlier in the code, prior to the `if`, that prevents the `if` running at all.

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com, this event is fully supported by all modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=hashchange

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome on OSX

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I've taken all my code out and just put the if statement in alone.

I'm on Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit), OSX.

Using JSP btw to call the JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure alerts haven't been disabled (had that last time myself)...

Comment: Oh gosh that is what it was. Thanks @Shikkediel and everyone for contributing, feeling pretty stupid right now..

Comment: No need for that, same thing got me stumped a while back. ;-)